# How to auto restart a crashed app?

Tags: xubuntu, restart, docky, crash

Im tired that everytime my dock (i use docky) crash i have to manual reopen it.

There is a way for auto restart docky everytime it crash?

I mean something that can auto reopen the app when it crash...

ps i'm a newby non english on xubuntu

Answer (score 5):

Open your terminal and type as

```
gedit autostart.sh
```

then paste this code as it as

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
if [ ! `pgrep docky` ] ; then
/usr/bin/autorestart1.sh
fi
sleep 30
done
```

save it & close.

Then again in the terminal type as

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/autostart1.sh
```

and paste

```
cd /usr/bin/
docky
```

save & close.

thats it now onwards. your application will be autostart after the crash,:)

Credit goes to [Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1883579)

Comment: how can I implement this to function the same way if a user quits the application? And is "autostart1.sh" supposed to be named "autorestart1.sh" as per previous file?